# How to start a App automatically in swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering if you know of a way in which n App can receive a messages/file or even "wakeup" while it is not active initially.
Please let me know if there is a mechanism or even if there is a path worth exploring.

Comment: iOS? OS X?  What do you mean exactly by "wakeup"?

Comment: In iOS, no this isn't possible. You could send a push notification which may show on the user's screen and the app will open from them tapping it. Otherwise, no.

Comment: It wouldn't be foregrounded but you can send a remote notification with the 'content-available' flag set. Probably not what you meant so @Fogmeister is right.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a mechanism and I never tested it but according to Apples Developer Library if your App is monitoring some area (up to 20 geofencing areas per App) and if you will enter that area, the Application will be relaunched, at least AppDelegate will be called even if the app is terminated.

> If a region boundary crossing occurs while your iOS app is not
>   running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in
>   the background so that it can process the event.

[Read here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) Maybe this could help you a little. I'd love to see your finding on that topic. :)

I have some fancy idea about this. You could update the geofencing areas each time you will enter one. So you will have an App that will relaunch it self over an over if you have good network connection and are mowing around. :D

Comment: Thanks guys. What I envision is an App that awaits an external event that may occur when the App is not activated. I would like the App to monitor such signals in the background (perhaps a very small observer that will wake the App or at least give notice to the user.

Comment: Apple has a system - like the alarm clock but to my knowledge Apple does not allow interacting with it.